# Hardware vs Driver

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers, hardware-failure

I bought a Dell XPS laptop recently, and had some problems with the "Killer WiFi" which caused me to send it back to Dell (alongside other issues). I received it back with Dell saying it had been replaced with different hardware. However, when I check the Device Manager, I still see the "Killer WiFi".

Is it possible to have different hardware working with another driver? The reason I ask this is because I may have unknowingly restored my system to an older system image. If this is the case, wouldn't the driver restored be incompatible or not work, given that the hardware has been changed?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Tech support typically replaces parts with identical ones. When they don't that's the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shipped the machine back to Dell for a replacement part under warranty, they would have used the same model part if it was available (Usually based on a Dell Part Number, DPN).  If it's the same model, then it would use the same driver.

If you know what the MAC address of the wireless was before you shipped it back, you can confirm that it was replaced by looking at the new MAC address and comparing it.